# ImageReader returns the wrong format by .getFormatName() method

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have problem returning jpg format. When my file is in jpg format, the final format is jpeg. My method:

```
public String getImageFormat(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
    if (!iter.hasNext())
        return null;
    ImageReader reader = iter.next();
    ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
    reader.setInput(stream, true, true);
    try {
        reader.read(0, param);
        return reader.getFormatName();
    } finally {
        reader.dispose();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

I noticed that Image reader for jpg in orginatingProvider returns something like this:
[image]

I would like to receive the actual format of the photo, has anyone had such a case and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Are you saying there is a difference between "JPG" and "JPEG" ?

Comment: I just mean if I am able to return the real photo format, if input has a photo; image.jpg 'then I would like to return as jpg, if; jpeg' then jpeg. At the moment my method for 'jpg, jpeg' photos returns jpeg format and I can't tell them apart.

Comment: You cannot tell them apart because they're [the same thing](https://kinsta.com/blog/jpg-vs-jpeg/). jpg is just a short version since some file systems only had 3 letter extensions.

Comment: `jpeg` is the correct name as it is the mime type `image/jpeg` https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/ - `jpg` ist just the (old) file extension for file-systems where only 8.3 file-names were allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments already points out, there is nothing wrong about the format name. The actual format is really called "JPEG", short for ["Joint Photographic Experts Group"](https://jpeg.org/about.html). The reason `.jpg` or `.JPG` is typically used for file extension, is due to the fact that arcane file systems only allowed 3 letter file extensions.

If, on the other hand, what you really want to know is the file extension, use a `File` object, and extract the part of the file name after the dot. Using `ImageIO` is way overkill for such a task.

```java
File file = new File(...); 

String fileName = file.getName();
int index = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');

if (index >= 0) {
    return fileName.substring(index + 1);
}

// No period found
return null;
```